# How to resolve React state updating but not pushing values to props?

Tags: reactjs, undefined, state, render, react-props

I am fetching data from an API to build a page that will display recipes as a fun little app to add on to my "things I've built" list. I can run the fetch call and see that the state is updated in dev tools, but after adding a ternary operation to render this new data once the search is performed, the new state/data does not seem to pass into my child component props.

I've tried providing default values to the recipes prop

```
recipes={ this.state.results || {"id": 1, title: "test", "servings": "6", "readyInMinutes": 10}}
```

and I've tried setting `isLoading` in the `callback` of my `setState` call

```
this.setState({ results: resData.data.results},
 () => { this.setState({isLoading: false});} )
```

I've been all over stack overflow and other resources trying just about anything i can find...I understand the `setState` is `asynchronous` and I've tried playing around with every solution I can find on google rephrasing this question over and over, and at this point I assume its some precise problem that I am just not noticing.

**Main Component:**

```
class CookingPage extends Component {

    state = {
        results: [],
        isLoading: true,
    }

    isActive = true;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    // componentDidMount(){
    //     this.setState({
    //         isLoading: false
    //     });
    // }
    srchApi = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let validated = false;
        let query = document.getElementById('search').value;
        let cuisine = document.getElementById('cuisine').value;
        let diet = document.getElementById('diet').value;
        if(query){
            validated = true;
        }
        if (!validated) {
//code to notify user of invalid search
            return;
        } else {
            fetch('http://localhost/cooking', {
                method: 'post',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    query: query,
                    cuisine: cuisine,
                    diet: diet
                })
            }).then(res => {
                return res.json();
            }).then(resData => {
                if(this.isActive){
                    debugger;
                    this.setState({
                        results: resData.data.results,
                        isLoading: false
                    });
                }
            }).catch(err => {
                if(this.isActive){
                    this.setState({isLoading: false});
                }
            });
        }
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.isActive = false;
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='background'>
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-12">
                            <div className='container search-ctr'>
                                <Form>
                                    <div className='row'>
                                        <div className='col-4 plain-search'>
                                            <Form.Group controlId='search'>
                                                <Form.Label>Plain Search</Form.Label>
                                                <Form.Control type='text' placeholder='Recipes...Nutrients...Ingredients...Just search!'></Form.Control>
                                            </Form.Group>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className='col-4 col-cuisine'>
                                            <Form.Group controlId='cuisine'>
                                                <Form.Label>Cuisine</Form.Label>
                                                <Form.Control type='text' placeholder='Italian, Mexican, etc..'></Form.Control>
                                            </Form.Group>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className='col-4 col-diet'>
                                            <Form.Group controlId='diet'>
                                                <Form.Label>Diet</Form.Label>
                                                <Form.Control type='text' placeholder='Vegetarian, Vegan, etc...'></Form.Control>
                                            </Form.Group>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className='row'>
                                        <div className='col-12'>
                                            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-outline-light btnSearch" onClick={this.srchApi}>Search</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </Form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className='row'>
                        <div className='col-12'>
                        {this.state.isLoading ? (<div></div>) :
                        <RecipeList 
                            recipes={this.state.results}
                            onDetail={this.showDetailsHandler}
                        />
                        }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default CookingPage;
```

**Child component:**

```
const RecipeList = props => {

  const mapRecipes = props.recipes.map(recipe => {
    return( 
      <PreviewRecipe 
      key = {recipe.id}
      className = "preview-recipe"
      recipekey = {recipe.id}
      recipeid = {recipe.id}
      title = {recipe.title} 
      cookTime = {recipe.readyInMinutes}
      servings = {recipe.servings} 
      onDetail = {props.onViewDetail}
      />
      )
    });

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className = "recipe-list-ctr">
        <h4 className = "recipe-list-title">Title</h4>
        <h4 className = "recipe-list-servings">Servings</h4>
        <h4 className = "recipe-list-img">Image</h4>
      </div>
      {mapRecipes}
    </React.Fragment>
  )
};

export default RecipeList;
```

I expect a list of `RecipeList` components to display on the page after being mapped from the `props`, however I get the error:

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.

As I explained before, using dev tools and removing the `isLoading:false` from the `setState` call, I can see in dev tools that the `state` is updating to the data received from the API, so I am really unsure as to why it is not being passed through. My understanding of the life-cycle just might not be up to par yet, and I would appreciate and solutions or suggestions to help me debug and get back on the right track.

Comment: What exactly do you mean *"pushing values to props"*? Please cut this down to a [mcve].

Comment: @jonrsharpe the value of "results" is not passed down to the component "RecipeList" after the fetch call, thus giving me the error for "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the issue I believe. After days and hours of debugging, the issue came to be that my import statement for one of my components was importing from the wrong file. Thus it was rendering a component with props that were undefined.